# How to show buttons, depending on the presence of a token? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, token

I need your help. I have a number of methods: `login`, `logout`, `isAuthenticated`. I'm trying to make sure that when logging in, I store the token in `localStorage` and if I have it, show only the `Logout` button.
When I log into the system, everything is fine, but after reloading the page, I see the remaining 2 buttons instead of `Logout`. Although I have the token in `localStorage`. Tell me what my problem is and how to configure this logic for `logout` as well? Thank you very much

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
    this.authService.isAuthenticatedSubject.subscribe(isAuthenticated=> {
        this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    });
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout().subscribe(() => {});
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button *ngIf="!isAuthenticated"> Login </button>
    <button *ngIf="!isAuthenticated"> Signup </button>
    <button (click)="logout()" *ngIf="isAuthenticated"> Logout </button>
</div>
```

auth.service

```
export class AuthService {

  public isAuthenticatedSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public login(body: LoginModel): Observable<SignupLoginResponseModel> {
    return this.httpClient.post<SignupLoginResponseModel>(`${environment.apiUrl}/auth/login`, body)
      .pipe(
        tap((response) => {
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.access_token);
          this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
        })
    );
  }

  public logout(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/auth/logout`, {})
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
          this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
        })
    );
  }

  public getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token')!;
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = this.getToken();
    return !!token;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the value of `isAuthenticatedSubject` to true if the token exists, false otherwise.

```js
public isAuthenticatedSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(Boolean(getToken()));
```

Comment: You could just use `this.isAuthenticated()` instead of `getToken()`.